# Mule ESB Riak connector: How to configure HTTP over SSL endpoints

Tags: java, ssl, mule, riak

I have a question regarding the Mule Riak connector and its configuration possibilities.
I would like to configure the connector using an HTTPS endpoint. Now the connector contains a org.mule.modules.riak.config.RiakHttpClientConfigurationAdapter and not the Mule HttpConnector.

To make my approach more clear, I tried the following configuration:

```
<http:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape"
    validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0"
    receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000"
    socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS" />

<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="riakclient"
        class="org.mule.modules.riak.config.RiakHttpClientConfigurationAdapter">
        <spring:property name="httpClient" ref="HTTP_HTTPS"></spring:property>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

Of course that fails:

```
Cannot convert value of type [org.mule.transport.http.HttpConnector] to required type
[org.apache.http.client.HttpClient] for property 'httpClient': no matching editors or conversion
strategy found
```

Now, can you think of a way to actually reuse an existing HttpConnector (with all that SSL configuration setup)? I actually don't want to configure a HttpClient again and add this to the riak client.

**EDIT 1: Updated with David's approach**
I added the following configuration straightforward to get the reflection part done:

```
<spring:beans>
    <!-- get class instance of HttpsConnector for reflection -->
    <spring:bean id="httpsConnectorClass"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <spring:property name="targetObject" ref="HTTP_HTTPS">
        </spring:property>
        <spring:property name="targetMethod">
            <spring:value>getClass</spring:value>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>

    <!-- get method via reflection of HttpsConnector for reflection -->
    <spring:bean id="httpsConnectorMethod"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <spring:property name="targetObject" ref="httpsConnectorClass">
        </spring:property>
        <spring:property name="targetMethod">
            <spring:value>getMethod</spring:value>
        </spring:property>
        <spring:property name="arguments">
            <spring:list>
                <spring:value>doClientConnect</spring:value>
                <spring:value type="java.lang.Class"></spring:value>
            </spring:list>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>

    <!-- set method accessible -->
    <spring:bean id="httpsConnectorMethodAccessible"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <spring:property name="targetObject" ref="httpsConnectorMethod">
        </spring:property>
        <spring:property name="targetMethod">
            <spring:value>setAccessible</spring:value>
        </spring:property>
        <spring:property name="arguments">
            <spring:list>
                <spring:value>true</spring:value>
            </spring:list>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>

    <!-- call accessible doClientConnect() to retrieve HttpClient -->
    <spring:bean id="httpClientFromConnector"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <spring:property name="targetObject" ref="HTTP_HTTPS">
        </spring:property>
        <spring:property name="targetMethod">
            <spring:value>doClientConnect</spring:value>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>

    <spring:bean id="riakclient"
        class="org.mule.modules.riak.config.RiakHttpClientConfigurationAdapter">
        <spring:property name="httpClient" ref="httpClientFromConnector"></spring:property>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

Sadly, the invocation already fails on the reflection part.
What I do in Spring should be equivalent to this Java piece:

```
    HttpsConnector https = new org.mule.transport.http.HttpsConnector(null);
    https.getClass().getMethod("doCientConnect", null).setAccessible(true);
```

On starting Mule I get the following exception on the reflection part of this bean:

```
    <spring:bean id="httpsConnectorMethod"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <spring:property name="targetObject" ref="httpsConnectorClass">
        </spring:property>
        <spring:property name="targetMethod">
            <spring:value>getMethod</spring:value>
        </spring:property>
        <spring:property name="arguments">
            <spring:list>
                <spring:value>doClientConnect</spring:value>
                <spring:value type="java.lang.Class"></spring:value>
            </spring:list>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>
```

**Exception:**

```
ERROR 2014-08-26 11:33:22,021 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.mule.transport.http.HttpConnector.doClientConnect()
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1665)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'httpsConnectorMethod'
```

**EDIT 2: Helper Class** 
package com.mule.httpclient;

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.mule.modules.riak.config.RiakHttpClientConfigurationAdapter;
import org.mule.transport.http.HttpsConnector;

public class HttpClientAdapter {

    private HttpsConnector httpsConnector;
    private org.mule.modules.riak.config.RiakHttpClientConfigurationAdapter riakClient;

    public HttpClientAdapter() {
    }

    public void setHttpsConnector(HttpsConnector httpsConnector) {
        this.httpsConnector = httpsConnector;
        this.riakClient = new org.mule.modules.riak.config.RiakHttpClientConfigurationAdapter();


        try {
            try {
              Class httpsClass = httpsConnector.getClass();
              Method method = httpsClass.getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("doClientConnect", null); 
              method.setAccessible(true);
              // Cast not working due to too different HttpClient versions (3.5 vs. 4.2)
              this.riakClient.setHttpClient((HttpClient) method.invoke(httpsConnector, null));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public RiakHttpClientConfigurationAdapter getRiakClient() {
        return riakClient;
    }
}
```

The HttpClient library versions differ too much in order make the case successful.
Will need to somehow adapt those versions too.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient cannot be cast to org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
```

Comment: *"can you think of a way to actually reuse an existing HttpConnector"* - is this a puzzle? I think there's a different site for teasers: [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) ;)

Comment: Yeah, this is called gamification. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a way!

1. Change the visibility of `doClientConnect` on the [Mule HTTP
   connector](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/http/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/http/HttpConnector.java#L466) with `setAccessible`.
2. Use Spring to fetch an instance of `HttpClient` via this method.
3. Inject it `riakclient`
4. Profit!

Comment: Hello David, thanks for your answer. I think you mainly developed the Riak connector if I look at it, right? :)
I really thought about building a new RiakHttpsConnectorAdapter... would be the cleanest solution, isn't it.
Nevertheless, your approach outlined is very pragmatic and nice. Can you help me with the final detail in my edited question?

Comment: Create a helper class into which you inject the (lovely named) `HTTP_HTTPS` connector and which exposes a factory method that calls `doClientConnect` to retrieve an `HttpClient` instance and returns it.

Comment: Did this, but facing incompatibility issues between the connectors and Mule's HTTP client. I think whatever I write now to get further can become an enhancement for the Riak client. ;)

Comment: Oh I see one is the old Http Client (3.x) and one is the new one (4.x)... Yeah, this won't work :(